# RestMVC.js(Mongoose) & Node.JS - External model files

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I am using RestMVC.js module that uses Mongoose in turn for model declaration. Let's say I have a few files with model declarations, and a few of them use those classes for member variable ala:

```
// Foo.js file
module.exports.Foo = function(mongoose)
{
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', new Schema({
   TestMember: String,
   SecondTestMember: Date
  }));

  return mongoose.model('Foo');
};

// Bar.js file
module.exports.Bar = function(mongoose)
{
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var Bar = mongoose.model('Bar', new Schema({
   DerivedMember: Foo,
   Blah: String
  }));

  return mongoose.model('Bar');
};
```

What is the correct approach to reference one model from the other? I attempted to do require('models/Foo.js') and exports.Foo as well as mongoose.exports.Foo to no avail.

Comment: One approach would be to pre-load all schemas, but what is the best place to store and access them in?? I don't want to pollute global space, perhaps mongoose.Schemas array, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is

```
var ASchema = new Schema({
        BObj: {type: ObjectID, ref: 'B'},
        Amount: Number,
        Timestamp: Date
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`require("models/Foo.js").Foo`

Should just work

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's not the issue in latest version, I am using v0.4, let's try again ...

Comment: Apparently this http://rawberg.com/blog/nodejs/mongoose-orm-nested-models/ talks about .schema attribute, but it implies that all models and schemas have to be declared in the same file.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html works if I declare member in Bar as  DerivedMember: [Foo], but this is an array and I need just a single object

Comment: According to https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/188, single instance members are not allowed.

Comment: It works when using mongoose.model('Foo').schema, however if I declare  Foo as member of Bar then Foo model is not loaded and throws an error. Is there a better approach to this?